# Produce a Hash from Keepass with Keyfile

Tags: keepass, hashcat

How to produce a hash value from Keepass 2 AES / with keyfile ? I tried `keepass2john.py`, but there is no argument for key file.

> **Keepass 2 AES / with keyfile**  $keepass$*2*6000*222*15b6b685bae998f2f608c909dc554e514f2843fbac3c7c16ea3600cc0de30212*c417098b445cfc7a87d56ba17200836f30208d38f75a4169c0280bab3b10ca2a*0d15a81eadccc58b1d3942090cd0ba66*57c4aa5ac7295a97da10f8b2f2d2bfd7a98b0faf75396bc1b55164a1e1dc7e52*2b822bb7e7d060bb42324459cb24df4d3ecd66dc5fc627ac50bf2d7c4255e4f8*1*64*aaf72933951a03351e032b382232bcafbeeabc9bc8e6988b18407bc5b8f0e3cc

*(above example copied from https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes)*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is support for KeePass databases using key files on the current release of KeePass2John.(c/exe).

**::EXAMPLE::**

```
<Exe_Path>\keepass2john.exe -i [0-98048] -k <Key_Path>\key_file.key <DB_File_Path>\DB_File.kdb
```

I have my doubts as to how accurate the final product is as I cannot seem to personally produce a hash that is interpretable to HashCat or JTR.  I have seen that others are having similar problems so I imagine that either it is not working quite right or my brand of misunderstanding is fairly common.

Good Luck.

Comment: Also, in my case I am working with a 2.x version database on the most current KeePass platform so it is also possible that KeePass has just gotten ahead of the issues that the KeePass2John hash extraction was taking advantage of.

Comment: You just need to remove the database name from the beginning of the hash in order for hashcat to understand it.